# How do put multiple html elements on the same row in a td

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```html
<td class='bid-floor-col'>
  <input type='text' class='bid-floor-input' value='foo' />
  <button class='bid-floor-save'>save</button>
</td>
```

I would like the input and the button to appear on the same row, i.e. input on left, button on right.  How do I do that?

Comment: do you use any css? if so please post it.

Answer (score 1):

I literally just cut and paste your  into a proper HTML doc and it works by default.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='bid-floor-col'>
      <input type='text' class='bid-floor-input float-left' data-id='<%=ads.id %>' value='<%= display_price_floor(ads) %>' />
      <button class='bid-floor-save float-right' data-id='<%=ads.id %>'>save</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Screen cap of preview. Same result in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: By default, that is the case. The OP failed to post their CSS code, which is evidently influencing the layout of the elements.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I never isolated it enough.  The page is part of this Ruby on Rails app and within that context it lays out the two elements vertically.  The codebase is not mine, and I'm a total newb to javascript.  Do you have any intuition where I should look?  The table does have headers.  Could they be affecting the situation?

Comment: The only effect of float-left/float-right class is the side to which the respective control is justified.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, and here are 2 ways to do so:

**1) Using inline-block:**

```html
<td class='bid-floor-col'>
  <div style="display: block">
    <input type='text' style="display: inline-block; float: left" class='bid-floor-input' data-id='<%=ads.id %>' value='<%= display_price_floor(ads) %>' />
    <button class='bid-floor-save' style="display: inline-block; float: right" data-id='<%=ads.id %>'>save</button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

**2) Using Grid-template:**

```css
.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<td class='bid-floor-col'>
  <div class='gridContainer'>
    <input type='text' style=" float: left" class='bid-floor-input' data-id='<%=ads.id %>' value='<%= display_price_floor(ads) %>' />
    <button class='bid-floor-save' style=" float: right" data-id='<%=ads.id %>'>save</button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks for answering the question rather than telling me that the example works when in isolation.